# Newton's 2nd Law for car on a highway

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, rotational-dynamics, free-body-diagram, drag

So I was trying to get the equations of motion of a car driven on a highway and that is affected by drag (other dissipative forces are neglected) via the use of Newton's 2nd Law. I supposed that the driving force was the one coming from the combustion of some amount of injected fuel. To describe it, I used the power formula, $F=P/v$. In this case, the power would be the derivative of the efficient energy coming from the motor (combustion of fuel), $d/dt\ [\eta E_{motor}]$. From here, the power expression can be found, and, consequently, the driving force one too:
\begin{align*}
P&=\eta \frac{dE_{motor}}{dt}=\eta \frac{d}{dt}[c_f m_f]=\eta\ c_f \dot{m}_f\ ;\\
F&=\frac{P}{v}=\eta\ c_f \frac{\dot{m}_f}{v},
\end{align*}
where $\eta$ is the percentage of efficient motor energy that "gets to the wheels", $c_f$ is the specific energy density of the type of fuel it's used [J/kg], and $m_f$ is the mass of injected fuel [kg].

At last, we just introduce the latter equation in Newton's 2nd Law:
\begin{align*}
\sum F &= ma\\
ma &=F-F_d\\
a &=\frac{\eta\ c_f}{m} \frac{\dot{m}_f}{v} - \frac{\kappa}{m} v^2
\end{align*}
The main problem I wanted to get at is that I can't solve this differential equation if there's $\dot{m}_f$ in it. Thus, I need to get $\dot{m}_f$ in terms of $t$, $x$, $v$ or $a$ to be able to solve it.

As for now I've thought of two possibilities: either invent some expression  for $\dot{m}_f$ that only includes $t$, or either using the mechanical energy formula. And by that, I mean this one:
\begin{align*}
ME=\eta \int P_{motor} dt =\eta \int c_f \dot{m}_f dt &= KE+PE+E_{drag}\\
\eta\ c_f \dot{m}_f &= \frac{d}{dt}[KE+E_{drag}]\\
\dot{m}_f &= \frac{1}{\eta\ c_f}\frac{d}{dt}[KE+E_{drag}].
\end{align*}

I'd need some advice on which of those two is the best option or even if there's any other possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Energy conservation:
Let $ P = $ engine power.
Then in time dt

engine energy in = change in vehicle K.E. + drag energy loss:

$ P \ dt = d(mv^2/2) + kv^2 \ dx $

$ P \ dt = mv \ dv + kv^2 \ dx $

$ P = mv \ dv/dt + kv^3 $

This is a 1st order nonlinear ODE in v but is separable:

$ dv/dt = (P - kv^3)/mv $

$ m \ \int v \ dv/(P-kv^3) = t $
and have fun with that integral or thereafter solving for v(t)!

Comment: I just noticed you can derive the exact same answer using force instead of energy, as you did.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is for constant power, right? And if I wanted it for time dependant power, could I use $P = mv \ dv/dt + kv^3$ in Newton's 2nd Law? Or maybe solve $dv/dt = (P(t) - kv^3)/mv$? What do you think?

Comment: Also, what do you think about the rotational and translational KE coming from the wheels, should I add it?

Comment: Varying engine power:  you'd have to solve the ODE with P=P(t) or P(v).  Good luck with that.

Comment: Wheel K.E.: yes you should.  It woud be part of the K.E. term.  You are still ignoring tire friction of course.  If that were zero there would of course be no tire rotation at all and no extra K.E. term.  If it were small then there would probably be slip so there would be no easy determination of $ \omega_{wheel} $ vs. v.

Comment: Ok, I'll add friction. What equations could I use to describe the wheel movement of the form $\tau=Fr$ and $\tau=I\alpha$? Like what forces affect the torque of the wheel?

Comment: Just modify m $ \rightarrow m + 2I/R^2, I = wheel rotational inertia, R = wheel radius.  Don't forget you probably have 4 tires!  Try to check my work.